# Discord: Trying to patch a user info

Tags: discord, discord.js

I am testing how to do api requests againts some discord endpoints. I have Access Token got from Oauth2 process. First tried, using postman, a simple:

```
 https://discord.com/api/v9/users/@me
```

It worked. but then tried to patch a user:

```
https://discord.com/api/v9/guilds/xxx/members/zzz
```

I get an error 401 Unauthorized.

I understand I need some permission, but I can not find which one. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: To fetch a user from a guild, you also have to make sure that the client to whom the token belongs is in the guild you try to fetch the user from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `/guilds/{guild.id}/members/{user.id}` endpoint does not accept access tokens as a form of authentication, instead you need to use a bot.

You can take a look at how to make a bot and get its token [here](https://discordjs.guide/preparations/setting-up-a-bot-application.html)

Note that for the Autherization header with a bot token the type is not `Bearer` but `Bot`